# menu with sub-menu hover-over effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following lines in my website - **http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LhDnu/** that creates a sidebar menu.

As the user hovers their mouse over a parent, listed item with child-links within it, a sub-menu appears.

However, when the mouse moves over to select one of the child-links, it removes the sub-menu listed items.

How can I modify the *codepen* above so that it will allow the user to select one of the sub-menu items?

Comment: The problem is that the sub menu is too far away, so you are no longer hovering over the parent when you move your mouse towards it. Depending on how you wanted it to look, you could either move the sub menu closer or leave it as it is but create a transparent "bridge" between them so that the hover effect doesn't die.

Comment: Thanks for the response John.  Could you please provide me with an example of how I would go about creating a transparent bridge?

Comment: It would be a particularly cumbersome fix and could easily cause usability issues of its own, but it would basically be a `position: absolute` block with no background-color (or 0 opacity), sort of wedged into the gap. You could create a pseudo element on either the top level or sub menu to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind.  Here is the solution - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LzpyK/.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working code for you, in css dropdown menus try to work with `display:none` & `display:block` not with the `opacity`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/luGDK/

Comment: Thanks for the response Saif.  The sidebar needs the padding space around it to go with the visual consistency of the website and this may be why I'm still getting the same sort of results when hovering over the child items.  Using `display: none`, I also lose the gradual transition effect.